# Numerical scheme for the heat equation on the icosahedral hexagonal grid

Tags: pde, finite-difference, numerics, parabolic-pde

I have a predefined grid([like this](https://github.com/vraid/earthgen-old)) that is spawned from a regular icosahedradron. It consists of many hexagons and 12 pentagons (corresponding to icosahedradron vertexes). I can tweak the granularity of a grid, but I did not find a way to port this method on a sphere.

I want to solve the heat equation on such a grid:

$\frac{\partial u}{\partial t} - \Delta u = f(x, y, t)$

with some simple border conditions for $u$

I failed to find good resources with numerical schemes and proof of their stability. There is an obvious scheme:

Hexagon:

$\frac{u_i^{n + 1} - u_i^n}{\Delta t} = \frac{1}{6}\cdot \frac{ - 6u_i^n + \sum\limits^{6}_{j = 1}u_j}{d^2} + f^n_i$

Pentagon:

$\frac{u_i^{n + 1} - u_i^n}{\Delta t} = \frac{1}{5}\cdot \frac{ - 5u_i^n + \sum\limits^{5}_{j = 1}u_j}{d^2} + f^n_i$

where $u_j$ are neighbours of $u_i$ and $d$ is a half of center-to-center distnance.

This scheme's error is probably $O(\Delta t) + O(\Delta h^2)$ as it is proofed [here behind a paywall](https://doi.org/10.1080/00207160.2013.864392) for a regular hexagonal grid, not for spherical one with the pentagon though. I bet there are some instabilities that are occurring near pentagons. Maybe they will go away by making the scheme implicit, I don't know.

Another problem is how to store such a grid, I [know](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexagonal_Efficient_Coordinate_System) there is a way to store such a grid if it is on a plane, but I could not port it to a sphere on my own.

And another question that I have is how to extend the hexagonal grid from only the surface to some depth, making it model a spherical layer.

There are some resources for a hexagonal grid on a plane, but it seems like nothing for one on a sphere.

To summarise:

- Where to find materials to get good schemas for the heat equation on this grid?
- How to store it?
- How to extend it to model spherical layer?

Comment: It would probably be easier if you add the centerpoints and subdivide the polygons into triangles using radial segments. Then you can use standard finite-element approaches to a triangular grid.

Comment: That is, sadly, true. There are much more resources for triangular meshes than for this one. If you got some good papers and/or tutorials though, I would appreciate them. Also, is there any better strategy for combining triangles' values than to average them?

Comment: I second the suggestion of converting the mesh to a triangular one. Nothing is to be gained from sticking with non-standard element shapes.

Comment: Stability and accuracy both have to do with a limit in which the grid gets small. But small compared to what? In 2d small compared to a typical feature of the solution. Here, also small with respect to the curvature of the sphere.